# Passing arguments to Hazelcast MapStore

Tags: cassandra, parameter-passing, hazelcast

I want to write my own `MapStore` which will access Cassandra.

I would like to be able to pass arguments such as Cassandra's address, how can I do this assuming I can use the constructor.

I'm using `Dropwizard` and specifically `dropwizard-cassandra` library.

Comment: Dear danieln, kindly review my answer and mark it solved if it works for you. Thank you

Comment: what I ended up doing eventually is implemeting ``MapStoreFactory``, so I could pass arguments to the ``MapStore`` constructor, like this: 
``mapStoreConfig.setFactoryImplementation((MapStoreFactory<UUID, TenantApps>) (mapName, properties) -> { if(mapName.equals("x")) { return mapStore; } return null; });
``

Comment: kindly, accept the answer if you're satisfied. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

@danieln

@noctarius showed the declarative way to specify properties in `hazelcast.xml`.

But `MapLoader` doesn't have a way to inject this property to the instance.

To do that, you need to implement `MapLoaderLifecycleSupport` interface.
Properties will me injected to `init()` method

```
public interface MapLoaderLifecycleSupport {
/**
 * Initializes this MapLoader implementation. Hazelcast will call
 * this method when the map is first used on the
 * HazelcastInstance. Implementation can
 * initialize required resources for the implementing
 * mapLoader, such as reading a config file and/or creating a
 * database connection. References to maps, other than the one on which
 * this {@code MapLoader} is configured, can be obtained from the
 * {@code hazelcastInstance} in this method's implementation.
 * <p>
 * On members joining a cluster, this method is executed during finalization
 * of the join operation, therefore care should be taken to adhere to the
 * rules for {@link com.hazelcast.spi.PostJoinAwareService#getPostJoinOperation()}.
 * If the implementation executes operations which may wait on locks or otherwise
 * block (e.g. waiting for network operations), this may result in a time-out and
 * obstruct the new member from joining the cluster. If blocking operations are
 * required for initialization of the {@code MapLoader}, consider deferring them
 * with a lazy initialization scheme.
 * </p>
 *
 * @param hazelcastInstance HazelcastInstance of this mapLoader.
 * @param properties        Properties set for this mapStore. see MapStoreConfig
 * @param mapName           name of the map.
 */
void init(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance, Properties properties, String mapName);

/**
 * Hazelcast will call this method before shutting down.
 * This method can be overridden to clean up the resources
 * held by this map loader implementation, such as closing the
 * database connections, etc.
 */
void destroy();
}
```

We don't have Cassandra example, but we do have Mongo example [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/mongodb) at your disposal. This example illustrates the approach of passing the properties to the loader.

Also, we would gladly accept Cassandra example to [hazelcast-code-samples](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples), if you will be kind to contribute one.

If you have any questions, let me know in comments below.

Thank you

Vik

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast provides the option to pass properties (configuration) from inside the `hazelcast.xml` to the `MapStore` implementation. Unfortunately, you're right, there is no example in the docs that shows how to do that, but here's the link to the XSD schema: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/resources/hazelcast-config-3.7.xsd#L1731

For a documentation example, I pass the info to our docs team to add one :)